# Simple way of denoting a condition on a long equation

Tags: notation

I have a few equations that are rather long. They are 0 if the long part would become negative. Let's say they look something like
$$ x =\begin{cases} a+b-cd &\quad \text{if}\ \ a+b-cd > 0\\0 &\quad \text{otherwise}.\end{cases} $$
Now I would prefer not to write the whole long part again. Is there a simple way of writing this? I was looking for something like
$$ x =\begin{cases} a+b-cd &\quad \text{if}\ \ x>0\\0 &\quad \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
In my case there is no way of simplifying the expression $a+b-cd$.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This notation doesn't work because the value of $x$ is still undefined when you compare it to $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Superscript $\cdot^+$ is the way to go
$$
x = (a + b - cd)^+ := \max(0, a + b - cd).
$$

Comment: that's exactly the definition of superscript +, as indicated in my answer.